# in Javascript, how to modify a base64 image?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, three.js, base64

I am using Vue.js and Three.js to render alpha textures. The alpha information is held in the alpha channel of my textures. 
However, in Three.js, alpha values are ignored:

> .alphaMap : Texture
>
> The alpha map is a grayscale texture that controls the opacity across the surface (black: fully transparent; white: fully opaque). Default is null.
>
> Only the color of the texture is used, ignoring the alpha channel if one exists. For RGB and RGBA textures, the WebGL renderer will use the green channel when sampling this texture due to the extra bit of precision provided for green in DXT-compressed and uncompressed RGB 565 formats. Luminance-only and luminance/alpha textures will also still work as expected.

*https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.map*

Therefore, when uploading the texture, I want to modify it, by placing alpha values into the Green channel. As i know, I can only do it from the base64 data.

I've created a new Image, set the src to the base64 of my texture and applied modification on load of this new Image.
Here is my current code:

```js
selectAlphaTextureFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const base64String = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
// ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁ ⋁
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
          var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          for (var y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {
              var index = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
              var alpha = imageData.data[index + 3];
              imageData.data[index + 1] = alpha;
            }
          }
      };
      image.src = base64String;
// ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀ ⋀
      this.applyAlphaTexture(base64String);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

As for now, I'm not doing anything with this new image, because I instantly get this error in my terminal:
`Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat '/home/cli-app/public/iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh[...]Jggg=='` (skipping the long base64)
and this in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8082/iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh[...]Jggg== 414 (URI Too Long)
Image (async)
reader.onload @ ObjectInfo.vue:290
load (async)
selectAlphaTextureFile @ ObjectInfo.vue:257
_ctx.selectedObject.filter.onChange._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ ObjectInfo.vue:20
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278
```

So I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know how to handle it.

(ps: I also don't know how to create a new Image with the width/height of my first image)

Comment: Try it with keeping the "header" in the image data. You are extracting it presently in this part `e.target.result.split(',')[1];`. That is, the "header" is *apart* of the base64 image. Without it it may be that  its being seen as an URL and thus a too long one.